# Need help exporting parsed results, via Nokogiri, and exporting to CSV,. Only last parsed result is shown, why?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is killing me and searching here and the big G is confusing me even more.

I followed the tutorial at [Railscasts #190](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri) on Nokogiri and was able to write myself a nice little parser:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.target.com/c/movies-entertainment/-/N-5xsx0/Ntk-All/Ntt-wwe/Ntx-matchallpartial+rel+E#navigation=true&facetedValue=/-/N-5xsx0&viewType=medium&sortBy=PriceLow&minPrice=0&maxPrice=10&isleaf=false&navigationPath=5xsx0&parentCategoryId=9975218&RatingFacet=0&customPrice=true"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("title").text
doc.css(".standard").each do |item|

title = item.at_css("span.productTitle a")[:title]
format = item.at_css("span.description").text
price = item.at_css(".price-label").text[/\$[0-9\.]+/]
link = item.at_css("span.productTitle a")[:href]

puts "#{title}, #{format}, #{price}, #{link}"

end
```

I'm happy with the results and able to see it in the Windows console. However, I want to export the results to a CSV file and have tried numerous ways (with no luck) and I know I'm missing something. My latest updated code (after downloading the html files) is below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

@title = Array.new
@format = Array.new
@price = Array.new
@link = Array.new

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("index1.html"))
doc.css(".standard").each do |item|
@title << item.at_css("span.productTitle a")[:title]
@format << item.at_css("span.description").text
@price << item.at_css(".price-label").text[/\$[0-9\.]+/]
@link << item.at_css("span.productTitle a")[:href]
end

CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
csv << ["title", "format", "price", "link"]
csv << [@title, @format, @price, @link]
end
```

It works and spits a file out for me, but just the last result. I followed the tutorial at [Andrew!: WEb Scraping...](http://www.andrewsturges.com/2011/09/how-to-harvest-web-data-using-ruby-and.html) and trying to mix what I'm trying to achieve with someone else's process is confusing.

I assume it's looping through all of the results and only printing the last. Can someone give me pointers on how I should loop this (if that's the problem) so that all the results are in their respective columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're storing values in four arrays, but you're not enumerating the arrays when you generate your output.

Here is a possible fix:

```
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["title", "format", "price", "link"]
  until @title.empty?
    csv << [@title.shift, @format.shift, @price.shift, @link.shift]
  end
end
```

Note that this is a destructive operation that shifts the values off of the arrays one at a time, so in the end they will all be empty.

There are more efficient ways to read and convert the data, but this will hopefully do what you want for now.

Comment: Also, if you're using `@` because you're coming from the Perl world and think you have to use that for array names, you don't. :-)  It means something entirely different in Ruby.

Comment: You have helped me tremendously @L2G! It added an extra column to the file but not a big deal. This will keep me sane until I fully understand this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you could do to write this more in the "Ruby way":

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("index1.html"))
CSV.open('file.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << %w[title format price link]
  doc.css('.standard').each do |item|
    csv << [
      item.at_css('span.productTitle a')[:title]
      item.at_css('span.description').text
      item.at_css('.price-label').text[/\$[0-9\.]+/]
      item.at_css('span.productTitle a')[:href]
    ]
  end
end
```

Without sample HTML it's not possible to test this, but, based on your code, it looks like it'd work.

Notice that in your code you're using instance variables. They're not necessary because you aren't defining a class to have an instance of. You can use local values instead.